# How to insert string_split output in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2, sql-server-2016

I have a string which I need to insert into a table after extracting values out of it. An example string is like this:

```
111111,1111,11.11,'2019-01-01-11.11.11.111111'#222222,2222,22.22,'2019-02-02-22.22.22.222222'
```

Using `string_split`, I can get split the values in different rows:

```
declare @s varchar(1000)
set @s = '111111,1111,11.11,''2019-01-01-11.11.11.111111''#222222,2222,22.22,''2019-02-02-22.22.22.222222'''

select value from string_split(@s, '#')

--Output
--111111,1111,11.11,'2019-01-01-11.11.11.111111'
--222222,2222,22.22,'2019-02-02-22.22.22.222222'
```

It gets interesting.

The output needs to be inserted to a table. I have thought about dynamic SQL, but am not too fond of that:

```
declare @SQLstatment varchar(1000)
set @SQLstatment = 'insert into MyTable (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) values (' + OUTPUT_FROM_SPLIT + ')'
exec (@SQLstatment)
```

It gets more interesting.

Col4 is of DB2 data type `timestamp`. I need to convert it to SQL Server 2016 `datetime2` data type using this statement I wrote:

```
declare @DB2_timpstamp varchar(30) = '2019-02-25-11.22.33.456789'
select convert(datetime2, stuff(stuff(stuff(@DB2_timpstamp, 17, 1, ':'), 14, 1, ':'), 11, 1, ' '))
```

## Problem

I cannot make this all work.

I want to avoid using dynamic SQL as much as I can. Most probably I've to use loops. A solution will look like this:

```
while(SOME_CONDITION)
begin
    insert into MyTable (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) values
        (Val1,Val2,Val3,convert(datetime2, stuff(stuff(stuff(Val4, 17, 1, ':'), 14, 1, ':'), 11, 1, ' ')))
    LOOP_VARIABLE_INCREMENT
end
```

Comment: You don't want or need dynamic sql or loops here. It seems you have data that has the rows delimited with '#' and columns delimited with a comma. You will need to split the values a second time to get columns. Why is the source data so hostile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, not an expert on SQL Server convertion functions but this will get you in the right track:

```
with 
r (value) as ( -- raw varchar value
  select value from string_split(@s, '#')
),
x (col1, col2, col3, col4) as ( -- values in separate columns
  select 
    substring(value, 1, 10) as col1, -- fix conversion here
    substring(value, 11, 10) as col2, -- fix conversion here
    substring(value, 21, 10) as col3, -- fix conversion here
    substring(value, 31, 10) as col4, -- fix conversion here
  from r
)
insert into MyTable (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) -- insert now
select col1, col2, col3, col4 from x
```

As you see, there's no need for a loop. Just normal SQL will do. Of course, you'll need to tailor the conversion formulas a bit, but this will get you pretty close.

Comment: Those substring pieces are not really a good approach. It needs to be a second pass through string_split.

Comment: I like this solution because it is simplest than every other one here, and I could add some other things to it too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to split twice:

```
declare @s varchar(1000)
set @s = '111111,1111,11.11,''2019-01-01-11.11.11.111111''#222222,2222,22.22,''2019-02-02-22.22.22.222222'''

;WITH cte AS (
  select value
  from string_split(@s, '#')
)
SELECT
   MAX(CASE WHEN ord=1 THEN v END) AS col1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN ord=2 THEN v END) AS col2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN ord=3 THEN v END) AS col3,
   MAX(CASE WHEN ord=4 THEN v END) AS col4
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY (SELECT value AS v, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0) AS ord 
       FROM  STRING_SPLIT([value], ',')) s
GROUP BY value;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a129f79cc62b7932e682f715cdc8abcc)**

Answer (score 1):

Using the *power* of [`DelimitedSplit8k_Lead`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/) you can split the items twice, and know their ordinal position (very important for pivoting). Giving you a nice simple statement of:

```
DECLARE @DataSet varchar(MAX) = '111111,1111,11.11,''2019-01-01-11.11.11.111111''#222222,2222,22.22,''2019-02-02-22.22.22.222222''';
--INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN C.ItemNumber = 1 THEN C.item END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN C.ItemNumber = 2 THEN C.item END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN C.ItemNumber = 3 THEN C.item END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN C.ItemNumber = 4 THEN TRY_CONVERT(Datetime2(6),STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(C.item,17,1,':'),14,1,':'),11,1,'T')) END)
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_lead(@DataSet,'#') R
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_lead (REPLACE(R.item,'''',''),',') C --Because we don't want those nasty single quotes!
GROUP BY R.item;
```

Comment: Beat me again by about 30 seconds. Well done as always.

Comment: There's tends to always a few of us at the moment with very similar solutions all posting at the same time, @SeanLange . I find it quite amusing at times. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that splits the string twice, and preserves the order of the columns even if they are variable length. I used [this trick](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207274/string-split-and-ordered-results#207293) to preserve the order of the values returned from `STRING_SPLIT`. I did not preserve the order of the "rows" in the original string since it does not matter what order they are inserted in.

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(1000) = '111111,1111,11.11,''2019-01-01-11.11.11.111111''#222222,2222,22.22,''2019-02-02-22.22.22.222222''';
DECLARE  @c VARCHAR(1) = ','
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT s.rowNum, t.value, t.columnNum
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT s.value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.value) AS rowNum
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@s, '#')s
    )s
    OUTER APPLY 
    (
        SELECT T.VALUE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CHARINDEX(@C + t.value + @C, @C + s.value + @C))AS columnNum
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(s.value, ',') t
    )t
)
    INSERT INTO myTable (col1, col2, col3, col4)) --do your conversions here
    SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN columnNum = 1 THEN value END), MAX(CASE WHEN columnNum = 2 THEN value END), MAX(CASE WHEN columnNum = 3 THEN value END), MAX(CASE WHEN columnNum = 4 THEN value END)
    FROM cte c
    GROUP BY rownum
```